# Can not set absolute positioning for SingHere field

Tags: docusignapi

When I make a POST request to https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx to CreateAndSendEnvelope, I set up a tab:

But in result document there is no SignHere field at all.
What should I do to place SignHere to desired place?

```
<Tab>
  <Type>SignHere</Type>
  <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
  <xPosition>1</xPosition>
  <yPosition>1</yPosition>
</Tab>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
<CreateAndSendEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <Envelope>
        <AccountId>a290cac9-e2c4-415c-8a47-900587258cce</AccountId>
        <Documents>
            <Document>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Name>Simple NDA.pdf</Name>
                <PDFBytes>Jo=
        </PDFBytes>
                <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
                <AttachmentDescription>Simple NDA</AttachmentDescription>
            </Document>
        </Documents>
        <Recipients>
            <Recipient>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <Email>Somemail@gmail.com</Email>
                <UserName>Betty Adams</UserName>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
            </Recipient>
        </Recipients>
        <Tabs>
            <Tab>
                <Type>SignHere</Type>
                <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                <xPosition>1</xPosition>
                <yPosition>1</yPosition>
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        <Subject>Please DocuSign this document</Subject>
        <EmailBlurb>Please sign this document using DocuSign...thanks!</EmailBlurb>
    </Envelope>
</CreateAndSendEnvelope>
</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a DocumentID and PageNumber for your tab. Adding

```
                    <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                    <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
```

to the tab definition should cause it to appear on the first page of your document.